# Event is not defined in vendor.js when running with webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, nativescript, vendor

I am trying to get webpack up and running and this is the last hurdle I am facing (I hope). My project builds with the command

```
tns build android --bundle --env.uglify --env.aot --env.snapshot
```

but when I try to run the project it starts compiling but then I get this error

```
ReferenceError: Event is not defined
JS:     at t.patchEvent 
(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.LudusApp/files/app/vendor.js:1:601603)
JS:     at new t 
(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.LudusApp/files/app/vendor.js:1:601547)
JS:     at 
file:///data/data/org.nativescript.LudusApp/files/app/bundle.js:1:786884
JS:     at jo 
(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.LudusApp/files/app/vendor.js:1:82594)
JS:     at Mo 
(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.LudusApp/files/app/vendor.js:1:81929)
JS:     at Do 
(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.LudusApp/files/app/vendor.js:1:81764)
JS:     at Fo 
(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.LudusApp/files/app/vendor.js:1:82157)
JS:     at Mo 
(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.LudusApp/files/app/vendor.js:1:81890)
JS:     at Do 
(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.LudusApp/files/app/vendor.js:1:81764)
JS:     at Fo 
(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.LudusApp/files/app/vendor.js:1:82157)
JS:     at Mo 
(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.LudusApp/files/app/vendor.js:1:81890)
JS:     at Do (file:/...
```

My vendor.ts file looks like this

```
// Snapshot the ~/app.css and the theme
const application = require("application");
require("ui/styling/style-scope");
const appCssContext = require.context("~/", false, /^\.\/app\. 
(css|scss|less|sass)$/);
global.registerWebpackModules(appCssContext);
application.loadAppCss();

require("./vendor-platform");

require("reflect-metadata");
require("@angular/platform-browser");
require("@angular/core");
require("@angular/common");
require("@angular/forms");
require("@angular/http");
require("@angular/router");

require("nativescript-angular/platform-static");
require("nativescript-angular/forms");
require("nativescript-angular/router");
```

In case there is something missing in my imports here is my @NgModule

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,   
    NativeScriptCommonModule,
    NativeScriptFormsModule,
    NativeScriptHttpModule,
    NativeScriptRouterModule,
    NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    NativeScriptUIChartModule,
    DropDownModule,
    TNSCheckBoxModule
  ],
```

Can anyone see what the problem might be or experienced similar problems before???